# Putting a Mapbox-GL canvas into an OpenLayers node results in the Mapbox canvas being slim

Tags: openlayers, mapbox-gl-js

I follow this [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mapbox-layer.html) but my canvas is slim.

I set a breakpoint here.

```
const mbMap = new mapboxgl.Map({
  // the node has a clientWidth of 674px.
  container: node
})
```

The canvas is 15px less wide.

```
<canvas class="mapboxgl-canvas" tabindex="0" aria-label="Map" width="659" height="981" style="width: 659px; height: 981px; position: absolute; display: block;"></canvas>
```

The result is a white column to the right of the Mapbox-GL canvas.

[image]

The only fix seems to resize the node which is the container for the mapbox-gl canvas. This will resize the canvas accordingly.

Comment: Possibly down to which definition of the projection each is using.

Comment: How are you synchronising the maps?  This method seems accurate when the global vector data is replaced with local data  https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mapbox-layer.html

Comment: @Mike That is exactly the method I am using.

Comment: Anyways... since this is closed here I will put it into the mapbox-gl github issues.

Comment: @Mike I have now reproduced this with exactly the same dataset, same version of mapbox-gl-js and openlayers.

Comment: The vector data in the example is not precise enough to see any problem clearly.  I do not see any problems with https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-butterfly-s0j9m?file=/main.js

Comment: @Mike The stretch tripped me. It is not that. There was a min-width: 100% on the mapbox-gl canvas which caused the stretch. I updated the issue accordingly. The problem is that the Mapbox-gl canvas is 15px thinner when the layer is created after the Openlayers map has been created and then added subsequently.

Comment: Question is now completely different from the initial one, and so comments do not make much sense now. This is not a good practice. Edit should not destroy/delete old question, just add new findings, prefaced with EDIT.

Answer (score 1):

I can fix the issue by force resizing the mapboxgl.Map instance once after a slight delay. I still would like to know though why the size isn't right in the first place.

```
if (!mbMap.resized) {
  mbMap.resized = true
  window.setTimeout(()=>mbMap.resize(), 500)
}
```